# How can I wrap an existing REST API into graphQL API using AWS appsync?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to convert my REST API into graphql using AWS app sync, the problem is I am unable to fine the right method or documentation on how to do it.

I have successfully created a schema, I am trying to give a resolver for it, but I am not sure what is the right way to do it.

Comment: In the document : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-http-resolvers.html

it says:

`In the Data types pane on the right under the Query type, find the getUser field and choose Attach.

In Data source name, choose HTTP.`

But when I click the "attach" for the query , it takes me to the Create pipeline resolver page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the creation of a pipeline, I changed actions > update runtime > Unit Resolver (VTL only). and then selecting the HTTP request as a data source was open for me to use. the document does not seem to have this information, anyways if you play with it for some time, you can get it (quite frustrating, ngl).